# How to takeout unique values from column and create another column with some condition after grouping in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have table A like this:

[image: Attached Table A]

what I want table B:

[image: Attached Table B]

when we do groupby(r,z) we get above combination but how to split v column from table A to v_num column
v_num is number mentioned in table A except 99, if 99 is there while grouping we should count it but v_num is apart from 99
if we get in group 1,2 combination we should seperate row.

please help me, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`spark>=2.4`**

```scala
spark.sql(
      """
        |select r, z, FILTER(v, x -> x != 99) as v_num, size(v) as count
        |FROM
        |(select r, z, collect_list(v) as v
        |from table
        |group by r, z) a
      """.stripMargin)
      .show()
//If you wanted to take the first element as v_num then change query as below

spark.sql(
      """
        |select r, z, FILTER(v, x -> x != 99)[0] as v_num, size(v) as count
        |FROM
        |(select r, z, collect_list(v) as v
        |from table
        |group by r, z) a
      """.stripMargin)
      .show()
```

Comment: Thanks!! and do you know how to do it in pyspark?

Comment: Its same. Put it in spark.sql() without pipe(|)

Comment: Thank you so much @Someshwar

Comment: added one more query in question, please answer for that!!

Comment: why you removed the `accepted` answer? I think the above original question already solved. If you need any further help please raised follow up query

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as mentioned by @someshwar but in pyspark DF API

```py
df = df.groupBy('r','z').agg(collect_list('v').alias('v')).\
select('r','z',expr('''filter(v,x->x!=99)''').alias('v_num'), size(v).alias('count'))
```

Comment: I added one more query in question, please answer for that!!